# Why 'yellow' isn't good for optional parameter of \fill, when it is the results of an \ifthenelse command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, ifthenelse, fill

Can anybody help me? Why are the 1st, 2nd and 5th code good but 3rd and 4th stop with warnings.

First code is OK

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\col[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Y}}{yellow}{red}}
\col{Y}

\col{R}
\end{document}
```

Second code is OK

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[yellow](0,0)rectangle(1,1);\fill[red](1,1)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Third code stops with
! Undefined control sequence.
 \equal
{Y}{Y}
l.7 \fill[\col{Y}]
(0,0)rectangle(1,1);\fill\col{R}rectangle(2,2);
?
message

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\col[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Y}}{yellow}{red}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[\col{Y}](0,0)rectangle(1,1);\fill[\col{R}](1,1)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Fourth code stops with
! Undefined control sequence.
 \equal
{Y}{Y}
l.7 \def\COL{\col{Y}}\fill[\COL]
(0,0)rectangle(1,1);\def\COL{\col{R}}\fill[...

?
message

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\col[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Y}}{yellow}{red}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\COL{\col{Y}}\fill[\COL](0,0)rectangle(1,1);\def\COL{\col{R}}\fill[\COL](1,1)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Fifth code is OK

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\col[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Y}}{\def\COL{yellow}}{\def\COL{red}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\col{Y}\fill[\COL](0,0)rectangle(1,1);\col{R}\fill[\COL](1,1)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Can anybody know, what it depends on?

Answer (score 7):

The optional argment to the path is handed to PGFKeys which needs fully exandable key names. (No, each color is not its own key, PGFKeys does a lot of work in the `/tikz` namespace to sort out colors and arrow tips without having to use the actual key `color` or `arrows`.)

The `\ifthenelse` macro by `ifthen` is not fully expandable.

While PGFMath has its own `ifthenelse` function it doesn't work nice with text/string and you might want to keep using the familiar `\ifthenelse` by using a special key that allows a similar use.

```
\pgfkeys{/utils/ifthenelse/.code n args={3}{%
  \ifthenelse{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}}}
```

This defines a key `/utils/ifthenelse` that takes three arguments:

1. the `ifthen` test,
2. the key(s) that should be applied when the test evaluates to true and
3. the key(s) that should be applied otherwise.

---

Depending on your overall use-case, I've added some alternative solutions below which all don't need `ifthen`/`\ifthenelse` but uses only the PGFKey system.

If all you want are shortcuts, then you can also just define keys `Y` and `R` or even define colors `Y` and `R`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/utils/ifthenelse/.code n args={3}{%
  \ifthenelse{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  col/.style={
    /utils/ifthenelse={\equal{#1}{Y}}{yellow}{red}}]
\fill[col = Y](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
\fill[col = R](1,1)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  col/.is choice, col/Y/.style = yellow, col/R/.style = red]
\fill[col = Y](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
\fill[col = R](1,1)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  Y/.style=yellow,
  R/.style = red]
\fill[Y](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
\fill[R](1,1)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\colorlet{Y}{yellow}
\colorlet{R}{red}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[Y](0,0)rectangle(1,1);
\fill[R](1,1)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need the else option. Therefore only Your first solution is good for me. Is there a function that converts a non-expandable key to a fully expendable one? For instance, in my 3rd code \SETFULLYEXPANDABLE{\col{Y}}.

Comment: @1111pataki It's not that easy as `\setfullyexpendable`. There are ways to make a string equal test expandable but not with `ifthen`. My first solution has an else option, you can do `/utils/ifthenelse={\equal{#1}{Y}}{yellow}{/utils/ifthenelse={\equals{#1}{R}}{red}{<something else>}}`.

Comment: @1111pataki Can you maybe extend your question to show the more complex problem?

Comment: There is no more complex problem. Your first solution is ok. Even the \newcommand\mycolor was good. I just wondered why the third code didn't work.